# How to disable Modal pop up box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When a button clicked it shows a modal box. That modal box contains two buttons. `OK` and `Cancel` button. When we click on the `OK` button it shows an alert message box, up to this I got correctly. But I want to disable the modal box when an alert message pop up. I tried lot of methods like

```
  $("modalFileStruct").('disabled', true);
  $("#modalFileStruct").fadeOut("slow");
  $("#modalFileStruct").addClass("fade");
  $("#modalFileStruct").setFocusable(true)
  $("#modalFileStruct").css('style','background-color: #000; opacity:1; z-index:1000;');

  document.getElementById("modalFileStruct").removeAttribute("tabIndex");

  $('#fileStruct').blur();
  $("#modalFileStruct").css("position","relative","z-index","99");
  $('#modalFileStruct').fadeIn('slow');
  $('#modalFileStruct').fadeOut('slow');
```

But it doesn't satisfy my need. Could anyone help me?

This is my code

```
   $("#modalFileStruct").modal();//This is pop up the modal box
   //This is the click function of OK button inside the modal box
   function fileInfoClicked(){
    alertMessage('Error',"Attribute name contains special characters: " + inps[i],
            'error');
            return;
 }
```

//Code for alert message box

```
 function alertMessage(title, message, type) {
$.msgBox({
    title : title,
    content : message,
    type : type,
    modal : true
});
}
```

Comment: In what way does the code you supplied fail to 'satisfy your need'? What, exactly is the difference between what you have achieved and what you want to achieve?

Comment: what happens when an alert box pop up? we cant do any process on that page until we click on the 'OK' button. right? So this is what i want to achieve when we click on the OK button of modal pop up box. But when i gave all these ,  it disables the entire background .

Comment: please provide your html code also so we identify your problem .

Comment: If I understand, you want to disable the modal until the popup is closed? right!

Comment: no.I want to disable the modal until i click on the OK or Cancel button of the alert message box.

Comment: I edit the code in which I included my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#modalFileStruct").modal();//This is pop up the modal box
   //This is the click function of OK button inside the modal box

   function fileInfoClicked(){
      $("#modalFileStruct").modal("toggle");
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this is not am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the user to force to click OK button instead of closing the modal when user clicks on page. by the way which plugin are you using? In Bootstrap use `data-backdrop="static"`